# Using bottom navigation - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bottom-navigation-bar-in-android/) tutorial.

Which was about using the bottom navigation bar.

This below part is the code from the MainActivity file:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
  
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  
        val firstFragment=FirstFragment()
        val secondFragment=SecondFragment()
        val thirdFragment=ThirdFragment()
  
        setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)
  
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.home->setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)
                R.id.person->setCurrentFragment(secondFragment)
                R.id.settings->setCurrentFragment(thirdFragment)
  
            }
            true
        }
  
    }
  
    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment:Fragment)=
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment,fragment)  #HERE
            commit()
        }
      
}
```

I got an exception of the argument when calling replace() in setCurrentFragment. 'flFragment' is the argument passed in the tutorial, but I'm not sure what I should pass there.

When I tried to pass a Fragment view id, the R.id. did not find the fragment id views.

When building it returns the error, 'x argument should be a View etc'

Comment: show your `R.layout.activity_main` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because of the Null Pointer Exception since you are not passing the correct `id` of the FrameLayout. Follow the below steps to solve your issue.

Before once check whether you have binded the bottomNav to your Kotlin file

`bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav)`

Navigate to your **MainActivity.xml** or where you have initialised the FrameLayout. Here in my case

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now in your Kotlin Code, **MainActivity.kt**.Here, we need to pass the `id` of the `Framelayout` here in my case

```kotlin
// This method is used to replace Fragment
 private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment : Fragment){
   val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment)
   transaction.commit()
 }
```

Comment: Instead of a FrameLayout I have a Androidx constraint layout, will it give the same results?

Comment: Yes @MakeTheErrorDie you can use `ConstraintLayout` too but I prefer `FrameLayout`. Because there is no need to use a Complex Layout for putting Fragments. Hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Example, the id of "flFragment is used as an id of the "FrameLayout" in mainActivity xml. Do check there.

Comment: I added the framelayout as you told but id but I got This Error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Put the frameLayout in a separate XML file... And include that layout in your MainActivity xml..